# Drawing the centroid for the contour of maximum area in OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, contour, centroid

I want to draw the contour with the maximum area along side that contours centroid. To do this I have stored the area values of the contours onto a list and selected the largest area as well as it's position in the list.

```
for i in range(len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    area_vals.append(area)
        
maxarea = max(area_vals)         #maximum value from the list of contour areas stored 
pos = area_vals.index(maxarea)  #index position of largest contour in list
```

I have then used these to find the contour with the maximum area and its moments.

```
maincontour = contours[pos]            #contour that gave the largest contour area 
M = cv2.moments(maincontour)      #moments of that contour

cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 6, (0, 0, 255), -2)   #drawing the centroid circle on the image
image = cv2.drawContours(img, maincontour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 5) #drawing main contour on the image
```

Am I right in using this method? Would this produce the desired outcome? From my results it looks correct but I wanted to double check the method and logic behind the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see where you use the moments to get the centroid. Please always show a reproducible set of code.

In Python/OpenCV, to get the largest contour, an efficient method is:

```
# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

To get the centroid,

```
M = cv2.moments(big_contour)
cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I neglected to include the centroid code for simplicity but I did exactly as you have written above. Regarding the ``#get larger contour`` can you please explain me lines 2 and 3, espeically line 2 as to why that ``if `` statement is true and works

Comment: Different versions of findContours returns different number of items. So this line sets contours to the first item if the number of items is 2; otherwise it uses the second item returned.

Comment: But what is the significance of first or the second item in contours based on number of items, that is what I do not understand. Also, what does line 3 do? Does it just take the maximum of the contourArea values found in the new contours? If so, then it is not doing that when I print it.

Comment: Line 3 uses python max to find the largest contour by contour area. As for the second line, review the documentations for OpenCV 3 and 4 at various versions to see what are the return items. You will see different items return. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/ At the very top is a version selector.

Comment: from this [docs.opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) I have found that the first item is the image, second is the contour and the third is the hierarchy. From this I can assue that line ```contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]``` takes in the contours. This makes sense. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, the whole concept of that line is the extract only the contours from all the return items from findContours, because the order of the contours is in different placements in different versions of OpenCV.